# script for sum with difference of numbers inside brackets in file

Tags: python

Let us say for example a file is there

```
aa[2:0]
[2:0] bb
vv [3:1]
4vv
fv
```

I have a huge file with similar lines with different characters with numbers in square bracket and outside. What I am looking for is a script which performs arithmetic operation as below only on numbers inside bracket. It should not take any number present outside the bracket
so the output should be

Step 1 Subtract element 1 with element 2

```
2-0
2-0
3-1
```

Step 2
So the total comes to be 2+2+2+(numberof lines)

I am able to add all the elements using

```
     total+=sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\b(\d+)\b', e)))
```

but solution to this problem is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: Whatever is generating this file, should be changed as soon as possible. How do you decide what arithmetic operation to perform?

Comment: operation is always first subtracting element 1 with element 2 and then adding all these elements. this file is a pregenerated file to work

Comment: Use regex to parse the string, the rest is trivial.

Comment: I am already using regex. But couldnt find a solution to find the difference. it is simply adding all the elements

Comment: Use two capture groups to isolate the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import re 

total1=0
total2=0
with open("file.txt") as f:        # 'fn' is the path to your file
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        m = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line)
        n = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', line)
        if m:
            for e in m:
                total1+=sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\A(\d+)', e)))
        if n:
            for e in n:
                total2+=sum(map(int, re.findall(r'(\d+)\Z', e)))   

print(total1)
print(total2) 
print((total1-total2)+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not automatic completely, you can automate it using a for loop

```
import re #Importing regex

#Spliting the text
file = open('gen.txt', mode='r') 
text = file.read()
modified_text = text.split('[')
more_modified_text = str(modified_text)
even_more_text = more_modified_text.split(']')

# For loop to remove and get the values
for item in even_more_text:
    if item == '':
        even_more_text.remove('')

#running out of names
def subtract_idk(index):
    result = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', even_more_text[index])
    some_new_r = re.sub('\D', '', result)
    val_1 = some_new_r[0]
    val_2 = some_new_r[1]
    result_sub = int(val_1) - int(val_2)
    return result_sub

val_1 = subtract_idk(0)
val_2 = subtract_idk(1)
result_eg = val_1 + val_2
print(result_eg)
```